# How to match repeating patterns containing special characters in Ruby using regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, string, pattern-matching

Basically, I am trying to use regex to match repeating patterns containing special characters in Ruby. I've been able to do this if I am given the number of times a pattern repeats but not dynamically. An example string I am looking to match is:

`Draw a square that is {{coords.width}} pixels wide by {{coords.height}} pixels tall.`

This can be easily done by using

`arr = value.scan(/\{\{(\w+?\.\w+?)\}\}/).flatten`

arr looks like this after I run this

`["coords.width", "coords.height"]`

But how do I write a regex which can match in case this pattern follows arbitrarily, for example

`Draw a square that is {{shape.rectangle.coords.width}} pixels wide by {{shape.rectangle.coords.height}} pixels tall.`

while also matching in case of the following(no ".")

`Draw a square that is {{width}} pixels wide by {{height}} pixels tall.`

Comment: Do you wish to match `{{coords.width.}}`, `{{.coords.width}}`, `{{coords width}}` or  `{{coords..width}}`? You need to state your problem precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the regular expression

```
r = /(?<=\{\{)[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?=\}\})/
```

[Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/2aeo7Cslxj9Ei5) / [PCRE demo at regex 101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JS5cOY/1)

I've included the PCRE demo because regex101.com provides a detailed explanation of each element of the regex (hover the cursor).

For example,

```
str = "Draw a square {{coords.width}} wide by {{coords.height}} " +
      "tall by {{coords deep}} deep"
```

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["coords.width", "coords.height"]
```

Notice that `"coords deep"` does not match because it does not have (what I have assumed is) a valid form. Notice also that I did not have to flatten the return value from `scan` because the regex has no capture groups.

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(?<=      # begin a positive lookbehind
  \{\{    # match 1 or more lower case letters
)         # end the positive lookbehind
[a-z]+    # match 1 or more lower case letters
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  \.      # match a period
  [a-z]+  # match 1 or more lower case letters
)         # end the non-capture group
*         # execute the non-capture group zero or more times
(?=       # begin a positive lookahead
  \}\}    # match '}}'
)         # end positive lookahead
/x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: Hi, I have written the regular expression `/(?<=\{\{)([a-z]+\.[a-z]*)(?=\}\})/` it works fine. But you have included something called `non-capture group`, I don't know what it is. Could you help me understand why you have included that? And also what other string doesn't work with my regular expression? Can you help me?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, if you want to repeat a series of assertions, such as `\.[a-z]+`, you need to place them in a capture group or non-capture group. `(\.[a-z]+)*` (capture group) and `(?:\.[a-z]+)*` (non-capture group) match the contents of the group zero or more times. If you wish to later extract or back-reference the contents of a group you need a capture group; else, both will work,  but a non-capture group is preferred as it tells the reader you will not be referencing the contents of the group...

Comment: ....You don't need the capture group in your regex, as lookarounds do not consume characters; just match `/(?<=\{\{)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+(?=\}\})/`.  Normally you would use lookarounds, as you have done, or use a capture group: `/\{\{([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)\}\}/`. This has problems, however. Your regex matches `"{{x.}}"`, which I assume is not desired, and does not match the examples that have more than one period, such as `"{{shape.rectangle.coords.width}}"`.

Comment: `you need to place them in a capture group or non-capture group. (\.[a-z]+)* (capture group) and (?:\.[a-z]+)* (non-capture group) match the contents of the group zero or more times.` this line clears my doubt very clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/)`

This did the trick. It matches anything that's within {{}} but I can always validate the structure upon extracting the occurrences/patterns

Answer (score 0):

`(\{+\S+)`

The pattern above would achieve your goals. It matches all non space characters within the enclosure.

Comment: Note that `\S` matches any character and the pattern could also match `{abc`